# Configuring PhpStorm, select text only, not whole row

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm and having this problem.

I don't want this when I'm selecting some words:

[image: PhpStorm selection]

I've used Notepad++ before and I want this:

[image: Notepad++ selection]

Please help me to configure this setting? Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's just the visual difference. There is no way to change the selection appearance in PhpStorm, it always colors the entire editor window width using the selection color, not just the text.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's a bit inconvenience.